# SwiftUI - List of Timers, getting "index out of range" when deleting timer from list

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui, timer

I'm really struggling with removing a timer from an array of timers, that are being displayed in a list.

I have a Model that stores the timer information. In this simplified example, it is just storing the timeRemaining.

I have a ViewModel that has 2 arrays, one storing Timer Models, and another storing Timers. Also has delete timer, create timer, and append timer array functions in the View Model.

Content View is displaying the timers in a List, using ForEach. It also has a Navigation Bar with an "Add" button at the top for going to another view for setting up the timers.

The User Added Timers View allows users to select the numbers of seconds, then add the timer. The Add button appends the seconds to the Timer Model Array, and adds a Timer to the Timer Array in the view model.

Everything works fine, except when I delete a timer from the list, I get an index out of range in the createTimer() function of the view model. I know what the problem is... I am hard coding the timer index when adding a timer to the Timer array in the User Added Timers view. I just have no idea how to fix it. I have tried for days to find a way of accessing the index of the ForEach and using that as the index for each timer in  the Timers Array... but I don't know if it is even possible to do that?

Anyway, I am completely stuck... any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

This code below is very simplified compared to the actual code, but it pinpoints the problem.

Model:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TimerModel: Identifiable {
   let id = UUID()
   var timeRemainingSeconds: Int
}
```

ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class TimerViewModel: ObservableObject {

   @Published var timerModelArray = [TimerModel]()
   @Published var timersArray = [Timer]()

   func deleteItem(indexSet: IndexSet) {
       timersArray.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
       timerModelArray.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
   }

   func createTimer(timerNumber: Int) -> Timer {
       return Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.timerModelArray[timerNumber].timeRemainingSeconds -= 1
       }
   }

   func appendTimerArray(timeRemainingSeconds: Int) {
       timerModelArray.append(TimerModel(timeRemainingSeconds: timeRemainingSeconds))
   }
}
```

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject var viewModel = TimerViewModel()
@State var arrayCount = 0

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.timerModelArray.indices, id: \.self) { time in
                    Section {
                        Text("\(viewModel.timerModelArray[time].timeRemainingSeconds)")
                    }
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    viewModel.timersArray[viewModel.timersArray.count - 1].invalidate()
                    viewModel.deleteItem(indexSet: indexSet)
                }
            }
        }
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink("Add", destination: UserAddedTimer()))
    }
    .environmentObject(viewModel)
}
}
```

UserAddedTimerView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserAddedTimer: View {

@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: TimerViewModel

@State var timerSeconds: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Stepper(value: $timerSeconds, in: 0...59, step: 1) {
            Text("Seconds: \(timerSeconds)")
                .font(.title2)
        }
            .padding()
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
        Divider()
        Button("Add Timer") {
            viewModel.appendTimerArray(timeRemainingSeconds: timerSeconds)
            viewModel.timersArray.append(viewModel.createTimer(timerNumber: viewModel.timerModelArray.count - 1))
            
        }
        .font(.title2)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 60, alignment: .center)
        .background(.secondary)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding(.top, 40)
        .padding(.bottom, 15)
    }
    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
}
}
```

Comment: Why doesn’t your TimeModel hold the timer instead so you only need to maintain one array?

Comment: Hi Joakim. I couldn't figure out how to add a timer to the Model. Still learning, but when I tried to add the timer to the model and have the createTimer() function add it to the model, I was running into a lot of issues with it not allowing me to access the timeRemaining property. Creating a second array was the workaround, so that I could access viewmodel.timerModelArray.timeRemaining.

Comment: Do you think you could give me guidance on how to add the timer to the Timer Modal? Would be greatly appreciated. Maybe that will also solve the index out of range error that I can't seem to solve. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are some issues to the code, one is that the closure in createTimer might be called _after_ you have deleted from your arrays so you need to check that by doing `if timerNumber < self.timerModelArray.count` before accessing the array.  Another strange thing is that you don't invalidate the timer when it reaches zero but maybe there is a reason for that? And in `onDelete` you do `viewModel.timersArray[viewModel.timersArray.count - 1].invalidate()` which means you always invalidate the last timer which might not be the one that was deleted.

Comment: I see. I will implement the first one and see if that helps. The last issue you point out is my main struggle. I can't figure out how to access the specific index for the timer that I am creating or deleting. Hard coding the index with timersArray.count - 1 was the only way I could get it to work, but that is obviously causing my index out of range issue when deleting a timer. Is there a way to use the index of the ForEach as the index for for the items in the 2 arrays? Or is there another more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: Another thing I realised when looking more closely at your code is that you can probably skip the timer array all together and replace it with a single Timer instance that you create when the first TimerModel is created and that you keep running until the last TimerModel has been deleted or has stopped running. This should simplify your code and you can update all active elements in the array in the Timer closure instead of only a single one.

Comment: The timers in the full code all have buttons to be stopped and reset, and have to be invalidated when I delete one, so I had to create separate timers for each. I feel like adding the timer inside of the TimerModal so I have one array of timer modals, and not to separate arrays, would fix a lot of my problems, but I spent hours trying to get it working and couldn’t figure out how to implement the timer into the modal.

Comment: Finally was able to get to my computer, the "if timerNumber < self.timerModelArray.count" was all it took to fix the issue! Thanks so much! Is there a way for me to flag your comment as the Answer? Now you have me wanting to add the Timer to the Model, gonna try to figure that out.